# Python - Replace String with Value from another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame with the following data :

```
average_x,  average_y,  average_z,  Result
1,2,3,x | y
4,5,6,x | y |z
8,7,9,z
11,12,31,x | z
67,56,43,y | z
```

and the requirement is to replace the value in result column with the value from their respective columns :

```
Result

Average X is 1 | Average Y is 2 
Average X is 4 | Average Y is 5 | Average Z is 6 
Average Z is 9 
Average X is 11 | Average Z is 31 
Average Y is 56 | Average Z is 43
```

I have tried following code but ends up with an error message :

```
df_test['Result']=np.where(df_test['Result'].str.contains('x'),df_test['Result'].astype(np.str).replace(to_replace='x',"Average X is " + df_test[average_x]),df_test['Result'])

df_test['Result']=np.where(df_test['Result'].str.contains('y'),df_test['Result'].astype(np.str).replace(to_replace='y',"Average Y is " + df_test[average_y]),df_test['Result'])

df_test['Result']=np.where(df_test['Result'].str.contains('z'),df_test['Result'].astype(np.str).replace(to_replace='z',"Average X is " + df_test[average_z]),df_test['Result'])
```

But getting following error message :

```
df_test['Result']=np.where(df_test['Result'].str.contains('x'),df_test['Result'].astype(np.str).replace(to_replace='x',"Average X is " + df_test[average_x]),df_test['Result'])
  File "<ipython-input-69-50ca75be0ce5>", line 1
    df_test['Result']=np.where(df_test['Result'].str.contains('x'),df_test['Result'].astype(np.str).replace(to_replace='x',"Average X is " + df_test[average_x]),df_test['Result'])
                                                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Please suggest how to correct the issue as I have almost 14-15 keywords where values need to be replaced with the values from their respective columns concatenated with text as well.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Saurabh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `apply()` to split `Result` on `|`, then capture the relevant `average_?` column when constructing the new `Result` output:

```
df.apply(
    lambda row: " | ".join(
        ["Average {} is {}".format(x.upper(), row["average_{}".format(x)]) 
         for x in row.Result.split("|")]
    ), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0                     Average X is 1 | Average Y is 2
1    Average X is 4 | Average Y is 5 | Average Z is 6
2                                      Average Z is 9
3                   Average X is 11 | Average Z is 31
4                   Average Y is 56 | Average Z is 43
dtype: object
```

You can also move things into a function, which makes it a bit more readable:

```
def describe_results(row):
    results = row.Result.split("|")
    updated = ["Average {} is {}".format(x.upper(), row["average_{}".format(x)]) for x in results]
    return " | ".join(updated)

df.apply(describe_results, axis=1)
```

Data:

```
df
   average_x  average_y  average_z Result
0          1          2          3    x|y
1          4          5          6  x|y|z
2          8          7          9      z
3         11         12         31    x|z
4         67         56         43    y|z
```

Note: I used `df.Result = df.Result.str.replace(" ","")` from the original data provided to remove spacing in `Result`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies with the following:

```
.replace(to_replace='x',"Average X is " + df_test[average_x])
```

Assuming this is a [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method, and assuming that you want to use the second positional argument for `value`, you can either drop the `to_replace=` keyword argument fragment as the message in the exception suggests, or add `value=` to that second argument.  Basically:

```
.replace('x', "Average X is " + df_test[average_x])
```

Or

```
.replace(to_replace='x', value="Average X is " + df_test[average_x])
```

Should work for your case.

Comment: Hello metatoaster,

Thanks , I have tried changing the code but there is no change is the result but the code did run error free.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to apply this change to every single instance where this particular `SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument` arises in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone , Managed to Solve the problem with following code :

```
for i in range(df_test.shape[0]):
if "x" in df_test.ix[i,"Result"]:
    df_test.ix[i,"Result"]=df_test.ix[i,"Result"].replace("x","Average X is " + df_test.ix[i,"average_x"].astype(np.str))

for i in range(df_test.shape[0]):
if "y" in df_test.ix[i,"Result"]:
    df_test.ix[i,"Result"]=df_test.ix[i,"Result"].replace("y","Average Y is " + df_test.ix[i,"average_y"].astype(np.str))

for i in range(df_test.shape[0]):
if "z" in df_test.ix[i,"Result"]:
    df_test.ix[i,"Result"]=df_test.ix[i,"Result"].replace("z","Average Z is " + df_test.ix[i,"average_z"].astype(np.str))
```

BR//Saurabh